# Angle between the magnetic field vector and the vector joining a satellite to a receiver station

Tags: vector, gps, satellite

I was wondering if someone could help me in finding the angle between the  magnetic field vector at a location and the vector joining a satellite to a receiver station. This angle is also known as aspect angle.

I know that we could find the angle between two vectors in 3-D space using the dot product of the two vectors but in order to employ that idea I must have the vectors in the first place.

How can I find the vector notations for the magnetic field vector at a given location and the vector notation for the line joining a satellite to a receiver station?

Comment: What GIS software are you using? Or are you just looking for some mathematical formula (I dont know anything about the subject)

Comment: I just need the mathematical formulae for the magnetic field vector and the vector connecting the satellite and the receiver station. Since the satellite is moving, the elevation and azimuth of the satellite keeps on changing. I dont know how to include these details into a mathematical equation. Also, is there any software available to compute this aspect angle directly without having to worry about the mathematics?